# Crystal lang: understanding method return type of Void

Tags: crystal-lang

It's not documented on the docs. But through experiments I've found out that typing the return type of method as Void, cancels the "last statement return" (that is good) making it returning Nil.

`def foo; "baz"; end #=> "baz" : String`

`def foo : Void; "baz"; end` #=> nil

`def foo : Nil; "baz"; end` #=> nil

The question is:

is above assumption correct?

Is there any difference between Void and Nil method return type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct. Some last changes in the language didn't get reflected yet in the docs. I guess it's time for me to write some more docs :-)

See this where this was merged: https://github.com/crystal-lang/crystal/pull/2701

So there is no difference between Void and Nil there, and the recommended thing to do is to use Nil in Crystal land (use Void in C bindings)

Comment: That's totally reasonable, one should be able to mark some return type as "nothing" if he wants nothing to be returned (escaping the implicit returns). Crystal is super great btw, just moved from "read only" mode and started to write some stuff with it!

Comment: @ClassyPimp That's great! By the way, today I added docs for this: https://crystal-lang.org/docs/syntax_and_semantics/return_types.html